# How can i read two same name json data in Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Guys its my json file But as you can see it have multiple Name - ID Or like that things. I have 2 Page in Xamarin. In first page i need to take datas from first part of json file. "ID"-"Name"-"Barcode".... etc. But in 2nd page i need take datas from CampaignList from Json file. But in campaignlist part have "Name"-"ID" too. So when i try take datas from CampaignList programm giving me datas from Root class. But i need take it from CampaignList. How can i take datas from CampaignList ?
My Json file :

```
    {
  "ID": 370,
  "Name": "NIVEA Sun F50 Kids Sprey Hassas 200ml",
  "Barcode": "4005900253330",
  "ClassID": 0,
  "PriceSales": 139.13,
  "PriceSalesWithTax": 164.1734,
  "PriceList": 205.26,
  "PriceListWithTax": 242.2068,
  "PricePurchase": 139.13,
  "PricePurchaseWithTax": 164.1734,
  "DiscountSales": 0.0,
  "DiscountOfficial": 0.0,
  "DiscountAdvance": 0.0,
  "DiscountReturn": 0.0,
  "DiscountManual": 0.0,
  "TaxRate": 18,
  "MonthlyPurchaseLimit": 0,
  "UnitCost": 0.0,
  "TermDay": 0,
  "Increase": 0.0,
  "WebPriceSales": 0.0,
  "_PriceSales": 0.0,
  "ProductCompanyID": 0,
  "Company": "NIVEA BIERSDORF",
  "FollowingAmount": 0,
  "CampaignList": [
    {
      "ID": 20458,
      "Name": "1A NIVEA KAMPANYALARI",
      "StartDate": "2020-04-13T00:00:00",
      "EndDate": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
      "Amount": 1,
      "ExtraAmount": 0,
      "MinAmount": 0,
      "Discount1": 10.00,
      "Discount2": 0.00,
      "Discount3": 0.00,
      "Discount4": 0.00,
      "TermDay": 0,
      "CompanyCampaignDetailsID": 0,
      "ProductID": 0,
      "CampaignRate": 0.0,
      "UnitPriceWithDiscountWtihTax": 0.0,
      "UnitPriceAfterExtraAmount": 0.0,
      "UnitPriceWithDiscount": 0.0,
      "RowSummaryWithoutDiscount": 0.0,
      "RowSummary": 0.0,
      "DiscountTotal": 0.0,
      "RowSummaryWithTax": 0.0,
      "RowSummaryTaxAmount": 0.0,
      "RowSummaryPriceSales": 0.0,
      "UnitPriceAfterDiscount": 0.0
    }
```

And its in c#

```
 public class CampaignList
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public int ExtraAmount { get; set; }
        public int MinAmount { get; set; }
        public double Discount1 { get; set; }
        public double Discount2 { get; set; }
        public double Discount3 { get; set; }
        public double Discount4 { get; set; }
        
    }
        public class Root
         {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public int ClassID { get; set; }
        public double PriceSales { get; set; }
        public double PriceSalesWithTax { get; set; }
        public double PriceList { get; set; }
        public double PriceListWithTax { get; set; }
        public double PricePurchase { get; set; }
        public double PricePurchaseWithTax { get; set; }
        public double DiscountSales { get; set; }
        public double DiscountOfficial { get; set; }
        public double DiscountAdvance { get; set; }
        public double DiscountReturn { get; set; }
        public double DiscountManual { get; set; }
        public int TaxRate { get; set; }
        public int MonthlyPurchaseLimit { get; set; }
        public double UnitCost { get; set; }
        public int TermDay { get; set; }
        public double Increase { get; set; }
        public double WebPriceSales { get; set; }
        public double _PriceSales { get; set; }
        public int ProductCompanyID { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public int FollowingAmount { get; set; }
        public List<CampaignList> CampaignList { get; set; }
        public List<ImageList> ImageList { get; set; }
        public int TotalQuantity { get; set; }
        public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
        public bool IsCampaign { get; set; }
    }
```

And i have 2 page in Xamarin. In first page it should show first part of json file from Roots like Name : NIVEA Sun F50 Kids Sprey Hassas 200ml But in 2nd page it should show 2nd part on json file from CampaignList Like : Name : 1A NIVEA KAMPANYALARI So its my Codepages  :
1st page (Its Works. It doesnt have any problem):

```
public async void GetJason()
        {

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var url = "http://api.lokmanecza.com/api/products/4005900253330";
            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);


            Root myProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response);
            urunadi.Text = myProducts.Name;
            kdv.Text = "%" + myProducts.TaxRate.ToString();
            firma.Text = myProducts.Company;
            dsf.Text = myProducts.PriceSalesWithTax.ToString("0.00");
            psf.Text = myProducts.PriceListWithTax.ToString("0.00");
            barkod.Text = myProducts.Barcode;
```

Second Page :

```
public async void GetJason()
    {

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var url = "http://api.lokmanecza.com/api/products/4005900253330";
        var response2 = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        CampaignList myCampaignList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CampaignList>(response2);
        CampName.Text = myCampaignList.ID.ToString();
        Miktar.Text = myCampaignList.Amount.ToString();
        MF.Text = myCampaignList.ExtraAmount.ToString();
        Oran.Text = "-----";
        Minmiktar.Text = myCampaignList.MinAmount.ToString();
        isk1.Text = myCampaignList.Discount1.ToString("0:00");
        isk2.Text = myCampaignList.Discount2.ToString("0:00");
        isk3.Text = myCampaignList.Discount3.ToString("0:00");
        isk4.Text = myCampaignList.Discount4.ToString("0:00");
```

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors or data (like json) as images.  Please take the time to post it as text and properly format it so its readable.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I edit it now.

Comment: @Cfun sorry brother i edit my question again. I trying speak as good as i can. But my english isnt enough for it i guess. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both pages are deserializing the same data into two completely different models.  This won't work.  The 2nd page wants the `CampaignList` data, which is a sub element of the data from the `Root` object on the first page.  There is no need to request the same data twice

instead you can do something like this

```
// pass the myProducts object from page1 to page2 on the constructor
// instead of calling the service again
CampaignList myCampaignList = myProducts.CampaignList;

// myCampaignList is a list of objects, you have to specify which one to use
CampName.Text = myCampaignList[0].ID.ToString();
Miktar.Text = myCampaignList[0].Amount.ToString();
MF.Text = myCampaignList[0].ExtraAmount.ToString();
```

it would also help a lot of you learned to use databinding instead of manually setting the values of all your UI elements

Comment: Brother You are awesome thank you so much <3 It helped me a lottt